# How to make a new request while there is an error? (fromJSON)

Tags: r, json, try-catch, jsonlite

I have a code where I make requests for an API using the **jsonlite** package.

My request is:

```
aux <- fromJSON (www ... js)
```

The problem is that there is a time limit on requests and sometimes the error is returned:

```
*Error in open.connection (con, "rb"): HTTP error 429.*
```

I need that, when there is an error the code wait X seconds and make a new request and this is repeated until I get the requested data.

I found the **try** and **tryCatch** functions and the **retry** package. But I couldn't make it work as I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach :

```
aux <- tryCatch(fromJSON (www ... js), error = function(e) {return(NA)})

while(all(is.na(aux))) {
  Sys.sleep(30) #Change as per requirement. 
  aux <- tryCatch(fromJSON(www ... js), error = function(e) {return(NA)})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apparently it worked.

This part of the code "error = function (e) {return (NA)}" only returns "NA" if TryCatch detects any error messages? Right?

Comment: That is correct. If any error is detected `aux` will have value as `NA`.